# tab icons not filling full width

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-tablayout, material-components-android, android-support-design

I tried several solutions but nothing worked. The tab bar doesn't fill the width of the parent on some devices. It works fine on devices like Samsung Tab 2 and doesn't work on devices like pixel 2(Like the image attached).

**[image: strong text]**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabLayoutTextAppearance"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorBackground"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        />
```

`

Comment: try `app:tabGravity="fill"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use`fixed` tabMode instead of `scrollable`

```
app:tabMode="fixed"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use also the `app:tabMode="fixed"` attribute.
Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      app:tabGravity="fill"
      app:tabMode="fixed"
      ..>
```

[image]

Check also the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#gravity_fill):
In the **support design library**:

> Gravity used to fill the `TabLayout` as much as possible. This option **only takes** effect when used with `MODE_FIXED`.

With the [**Material Components Library**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.html#GRAVITY_FILL):

> Gravity used to fill the `TabLayout` as much as possible. This option **only takes** effect when used with `MODE_FIXED` on non-landscape screens less than `600dp` wide.